# Excel - Different hyperlinks lead to the same website

Tags: excel, hyperlink, jasper-reports

I have generated Excel from a Jasper report designed in iReport that contains some different hyperlinks to websites. They all contain conditions such as

```
nvl(Country,'null')='SK'
```

When I open the first hyperlink in the Excel sheet, it opens correct website where condition is changed for

```
nvl%28Country%2C%27null%27%29%3D%27SK%27%
```

The problem is that when I then click on other links with other conditions, it still opens the first link.

Note: Links are longer than 255 characters.

Did somebody else face this problem? Can it be fixed somehow?

Comment: Does the `Address` field match the `Text to display`? It's possible that however this file was created, did not properly create the links. Without seeing the file, I don't know if this is what happened, but you can check.  Right-click on a cell containing the link, and choose `Edit Hyperlink` and verify that the Address matches what you are seeing? http://i.imgur.com/EEjnhZ7.jpg